# Async/await, doesn't reach next function

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await

I have this code:

```
const handleButton = React.useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      await client.clearStore();
      navigation.push('screen');
    } catch (e) {
      logger.error('error', e);
    }
  }, []);
```

I'm testing the `nagivation` to `screen`, but with the `await` I can't execute or reach the `navigation.push()`. If I remove the `await` on `client.clearStore` it's all ok, but the behaviour could be not as expected (I need first to clearStore then to navigate).

Any idea?

Edit:

My test is like this one:

```
import { useApolloClient } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
// After imports
jest.mock('@apollo/react-hooks');

// In describe:
describe('text', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    // @ts-ignore
    moment.mockClear();
    useApolloClient.mockClear();
  });

  // My test:
    it.only('should redirects to MyComponent when button is pressed', async () => {
    const apolloClient = {
      clearStore: jest.fn()
    };
    useApolloClient.mockImplementation(() => apolloClient);

    apolloClient.clearStore
      .mockReturnValueOnce(
        Promise.resolve('foo')
      );

    moment.mockImplementation(
      (args: moment.MomentInput) =>
        jest.requireActual('moment')(args || '2020-07-30T20:00:00.000Z')
    );

    const navigation = {
      push: jest.fn()
    };

    const rendered = render(
      <MyComponent
        paymentGatewayCode='khipu'
        allowToPay={true}
        expiresDate={'2020-07-30T20:00:00.000Z'}
        navigation={navigation}
      />
    );

    const button = rendered.getByTestId('button');

    fireEvent.press(button);
    console.log('navigation.push.mock.calls', navigation.push.mock.calls);
    expect(navigation.push.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
    expect(navigation.push.mock.calls[0]).toEqual(['MyComponent']);
  });
```

And I get this while running the test:

[image]

Comment: Did you implement `clearStore`? If so, are you sure that the promise that that function returns is eventually resolved?

Comment: Also, are you sure it's not throwing an error? Is the `logger.error` line being hit?

Comment: @Jacob yes, I'm sure, I have another cae where it hits `logger.error`, that case is mocking `client` as undefined

Comment: @trincot it's suposses to be defined. Actually, if I put the line of `navigation.push('screen');` above `await client.clearStore();` works all ok, but that's not the idea. I want to call the await first

Comment: What I'm getting at is if the catch block is getting hit when you try to run `await client.clearStore()`, that will prevent `navigation.push('screen')` from running. Is that your problem, or are you also hitting cases where there is no error and it's not reaching `navigation.push`? Might help if you posted what `client` and `clearStore` are so we don't have to guess.

Comment: Yes, the first guess of you is correct. Ok, I'll edit my question with more code, please wait

Comment: I can only repeat: are you sure that `clearStore`'s promise is getting resolved?

Comment: Hm, I just put ` const resolve = await client.clearStore(); console.log(resolve);` and it's `undefined`. Now I'm trying to define `clearStore`...

Comment: Now it's resolving some value, but the previous behaviour remains. I will edit my code again